# Encountering an error when running mut.py: "mut.py: error: unrecognized arguments"

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, mutation-testing

When i try to run mut.py i encounter this error

```
C:\Pprogs>mut.py --dcmotor_pid_control --dcmotor_tests -m
usage: mut.py [-h] [--version] [--target TARGET [TARGET ...]] [--unit-test UNIT_TEST [UNIT_TEST ...]] [--runner RUNNER]
              [--report REPORT_FILE] [--report-html DIR_NAME] [--timeout-factor TIMEOUT_FACTOR] [--show-mutants] [--quiet]
              [--debug] [--colored-output] [--disable-stdout] [--experimental-operators] [--operator OPERATOR [OPERATOR ...]]
              [--disable-operator OPERATOR [OPERATOR ...]] [--list-operators] [--path DIR] [--percentage PERCENTAGE] [--coverage]
              [--order ORDER] [--hom-strategy HOM_STRATEGY] [--list-hom-strategies] [--mutation-number MUTATION_NUMBER]
mut.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --dcmotor_pid_control --dcmotor_tests
```

My expected results was `[*] Start mutation process:

- targets: dcmotor_pid_control
- tests: dcmotor_tests
  [*] All tests passed:`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It literally says in the usage, what arguments you can use. Both you are trying are not in the list of valid arguments.